# Importing flask_bcrypt not working on Windows

Tags: python, flask, bcrypt

I'm building an app with flask on my Windows machine and I needed to import the flask bcrypt, I used the code line below:

```
from flask.ext.bcrypt import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

I got the error that flask.ext.bcrypt is deprecated and I should use flask_bcrypt instead:

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/exthook.py:71: ExtDeprecationWarning: Importing flask.ext.bcrypt is deprecated, use flask_bcrypt instead.
```

I changed my code to:

```
from flask_bcrypt import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
```

and I got another error:

```
bcrypt is required to use Flask-Bcrypt
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 2, in <module>
from flask_bcrypt import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_Bcrypt-0.7.1-py2.7.egg       /flask_bcrypt.py", line 27, in <module>
raise e
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

Using **pip show flask-bcrypt** It shows that I have flask-bcrypt install on my machine and I also installed flask:

```
» pip show flask-bcrypt                     
---
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: Flask-Bcrypt
Version: 0.7.1
Summary: Brcrypt hashing for Flask.
Home-page: https://github.com/maxcountryman/flask-bcrypt
Author: Max Countryman
Author-email: maxc@me.com
License: BSD
Location: /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Flask_Bcrypt-0.7.1-py2.7.egg
Requires: Flask, bcrypt
Classifiers:
  Environment :: Web Environment
  Intended Audience :: Developers
  License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License
  Operating System :: OS Independent
  Programming Language :: Python
  Topic :: Internet :: WWW/HTTP :: Dynamic Content
  Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules
```

Please what am I not doing right? I've searched many questions related to flask-bcrypt online and not help.

In addition to the above, I installed bcrypt with pip several times to be double sure it's properly installed, but each time, I got the following error:

```
No package 'libffi' found
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
               ^
  compilation terminated.


 raise DistutilsError("Setup script exited with %s" % (v.args[0],))
  distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error:     command 'gcc' failed with exit  st                                                                    atus 1

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for bcrypt



 No package 'libffi' found
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
               ^
  compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `bcrypt` extension, which `flask-bcrypt` depends on, was not properly installed on your system. Please install it explicitly using `pip`.

You might need a compiler in order to be able to install it. You probably had some kind of error message flashing over the screen when installing `flask-bcrypt`.

Also, your paths look a bit strange for a Windows machine. Are you using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows or such? In that case, you're actually working on Ubuntu.

Comment: I did installed flask-bcrypt with **pip install flask-bcrypt**

Comment: I got lots of error output as shown below each time I did: 
No package 'libffi' found
  c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
   #include <ffi.h>
                   ^
  compilation terminated.

Comment: I'm using mintty, a terminal emulator for Cygwin, the Unix-like environment for Windows.

Comment: Then you should install `libffi-devel` in your Cygwin enviroment: http://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86/libffi-devel/libffi-devel-3.0.13-1&grep (by re-running the Cygwin setup!)